# APT 401 Unauthorized [IP : 172.a.b.c 443]

Tags: apt, aptitude

I have ubuntu 20.04 clients and a nexus server. Nexus server is behind nginx which servs SSL with self signed certificats

On apt update from a client I get the error

```
Err :6 https://nexus.local.intranet/repository/apt-updates focal/main amd64 Packages
  401  Unauthorized [IP : 172.a.b.c 443]
```

I have create a file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99local-intranet to accept self signed certificate

```
Acquire::https::nexus.local.intranet::Verify-Peer "false";
Acquire::https::nexus.local.intranet::Verify-Host "false";
```

Self signed certificate on ubuntu clients machine is also installed under usr/local/share/ca-certificates/local.intranet.crt and then update-ca-certificates launched

Any idea to authorized [IP : 172.a.b.c 443] in apt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credential was missing in /etc/apt/auth.conf.d/nexus.local.intranet.conf

content of file

```
machine https://nexus.local.intranet
login my-username
password my-password
```